# MySQL Trigger issues

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, automation, foreign-keys

So I am trying to set up a trigger that when a new row to my user table is created a new row is also created in my profile table and the primary key in the user table is inserted into the foreign key slot in the profile table. This is the code I am using at the moment and it hasn't been working out.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER userID
AFTER INSERT ON user FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO profile (userID)
    VALUES(user.userID);
END
```

The foreign key on the profile table and the primary on the user table are both called userID

Comment: "and it hasn't been working out." - that is not sufficient....

Answer (score 1):

Saying `user.userID` doesn't mean anything useful in that context, you want to reference the newly created row using `NEW`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER userID
AFTER INSERT ON user FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO profile (userID)
    VALUES(NEW.userID);
END
```

From the [fine manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html):

> You can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases `OLD` and `NEW`. [...] `NEW.col_name` refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.